# jQuery AJAX issue - page keeps refreshing on submit and data not sent

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm trying to create an dynamic AJAX function using PHP and MySQL but have had little success so far. Its purpose is to update records in a database without refreshing the page or changing to another page.

On the page with the forms I have the following code:

```
// jQuery

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * from pm_schedule";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

foreach ($result as $row) 
{
echo 
"$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#updatebtn".$row['id']."').click(function() {
 $('#result".$row['id']."').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow')
 $.post('process.php', $('#updateform".$row['id']."').serialize()) 
 });    
return false;   
});";
}
?>
</script> 

// form

$sql = "SELECT * from pm_schedule";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
echo 
'<form id="updateform'.$row['id'].'">
<div class="tbl_header">'.$row['task'].'</div>

Due Date: 
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker'.$row['id'].'" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0,  
dateFormat: \'dd/mm/yy\', maxDate:  new Date(2013, 1,22) })
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker'.$row['id'].'" style="width: 100px; height: 10px;" value="'.$row['duedate'].'" name="duedate"/>&nbsp;

Status:
<select style="width: 125px;" name="status">
<option>'.$row['status'].'</option>
<option>----</option>
<option>Pending</option>
<option>In Progress</option>
<option>Complete</option>
</select>
&nbsp;

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
<input type="submit" id="updatebtn'.$row['id'].'" value="Update" 
style="width: 100px;"/>
</form>

<div id="result'.$row['id'].'" style="display: none; color: red">
Update successful!
</div>
<p>';}
```

On the page responsible for the processing **(process.php)**, I have the following code:

```
<?php
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["status"]);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]);

$sql = "UPDATE pm_schedule SET name=?, status=?, id=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($name,$status,$id));
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Things are a little tough to trace, but I don't think you're doing anything to prevent the default form submission behavior when the submit button is clicked. If I'm reading the above right, returning false from your click handler will solve your problems.

Comment: Tha's right, you can try to disable posting form by adding "return false;",  or change the type of button from "submit" to "button" as you don't want to post the form.

Comment: I've done that and posting has been disabled but the data does not seem to be updating in the db

Comment: Are you sure that the code is hitting `process.php`?  Do you get an error in the console?  Where is `$conn` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return false` is in the function called on `$(document).ready`, not in the click-handler, so I guess this causes the form to submit anyway after finishing the clickhandler. Maybe move the statement one line up:

```
echo 
"$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#updatebtn".$row['id']."').click(function() {
     $('#result".$row['id']."').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow');
     $.post('process.php', $('#updateform".$row['id']."').serialize());
     return false;
   }); 
 });";
```

As ripa said, a few more `;` should be helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

place `;` over here

```
foreach ($result as $row) 
{
  echo 
  "$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#updatebtn".$row['id']."').click(function() {
    $('#result".$row['id']."').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow');
    $.post('process.php', $('#updateform".$row['id']."').serialize());
    });    
   return false;   
     });";
 }
```